# unceraintity with arrayList storing

Tags: java, arrays, database, arraylist

```
public void openFile(){
        try {
            l = new Formatter("try.txt");
            System.out.println("Opened File");
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Did not open file");
        }
    }
    public void addRecord(){
        l.format("%s", nameField.getText());
        System.out.println("Added Name" + " " + nameField.getText());
        }
    public void onClose(){
        l.close();
    }

/*

So I am trying to store user data, I have a gui and anytime they click sign up i want to store the namefield in an array list, is it possible that anytime I close and reopen the program and someone else puts in their name it just adds to the array list instead of overriding what the earlier person put in?
Example is in my gui i type in mike as name, I close it and reopen it and put in john as the name, would that add mike and john or would it be just john? and how do I make them co-exist?
Thank you
```

It reads it to the file, but everytime I close the program and run it again it replaces whatever is on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

With `List` (of which `ArrayList` is one implementation) you can just use the `add` method. For example if you had a list that contains a single object which is the String "Mike", and then you execute `namesList.add("John")` (where `namesList` is a `List<String>`) then the list will then contain two elements: "John" and "Mike".

However, you also mention persisting data between program executions. By default all lists are purely *in memory* data storage, and will be cleared each time you close and reopen the program. To store them you need some form of data persistence. On the heavy end this would be a full database, but for a small project with simple requirements you can use SQLite - or even just a text file.

Comment: I know how to do it with a text file, but everytime it goes to the text file and I close and open it, the text file also changes. I'm stuck...

Comment: It sounds like your problem is in the code that is reading/writing from the text file in the first place. Take a look there, rather than in the `ArrayList` code. In particular see if your program is writing out to a file as soon as it starts up, before its read from it.

Comment: I am going to post the code that I have in the question. Thank You